# What is the adverb form of "custom"?

Tags: adverbs

What is the adverb form of the adjective "custom"?

**custom**

*adjective*

- made specially for individual customers.
- dealing in things so made, or doing work to order.

---

*The adverb form of the noun "custom" is "customarily". However, this question isn't about the noun; it's about the adjective.*

Comment: I don't think that there is a direct adverb, since "custom" in this sense is derived from "customer".  And other terms such as "bespoke" are equally oddly derived.

Comment: There is a compound verb _custom-make_, used most often in its past participle form, _custom-made_. For instance, _She has a custom-made suit that she wears to the Board meetings_.  Another adjective with the same meaning (though mostly UK) is _bespoke_, which seems to falute higher than _custom-made_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advebrb of *custom* in the sense specified is *custom*, as in:

> They **custom** make airbrushes for specific applications.
>
> We **custom** build each ad from the ground up
>
> He **custom** built pull-out drawers and added dividers measuring slightly
>   over 6 inches.
>
> We **custom** make each brake line to your exact specifications
>
> We had it **custom** fit without the train and it was beyond breathtaking.
>
> You can also get it **custom** engraved for an additional $10.

Comment: Yep, you got it!

Comment: You don't include supporting references; I haven't found any dictionary listing 'custom' as an adverb. I'd say that custom[Ø/-]make, custom[Ø/-]build etc are fully-fledged compound verbs; the [adverb + verb] stage seems to have been bypassed. But these usages are the way this semantic need is actually handled.

Comment: The examples of real use are supporting references, and it wouldn't be the first time dictionaries have made an oversight. As for compound verbs, there is a clear space inbetween the two words in these constructions and the variety of verbs taking adverb _custom_ as modifier would seem to argue that they are not 'stuck' together: _roast, rig, print, measure, make, create, engrave, install, formulate, blend, edge, machine, plan, pick, grow, forge, develop, craft, compile..._. All these and more may be found in the wild modified by _custom_.